# D3 to create same image with different data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is from a tutorial that I am using to learn D3 and I am trying out new things. I have data which correctly displays colors. But what would I do if i have two different data but I want it to do the same thing? I want the new data to be displayed under the set of image color.

```js
var data = d3.range(0, 50);
var data1 = d3.range(51, 100); //new data
var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();

var padding = 2;

// This is the total size of the data
var dataLength = data.length;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, window.innerWidth]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": window.innerWidth,
    "height": window.innerHeight
  });


// create a rect
var rects = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "first");

rects.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr({
    "fill": function(d) {
      return colorScale(d);
    },
    "x": function(d, i) {
      return x(d);
    },
    "width": window.innerWidth / dataLength - padding,
    "height": 50
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but one approach is creating a function to draw the rectangles (here called `draw`), which accepts different data arrays as arguments.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data1 = d3.range(0, 50);
var data2 = d3.range(51, 100); //new data
var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();
var yPos = 10;

var padding = 2;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": window.innerWidth,
    "height": window.innerHeight
  });

draw(data1);
draw(data2);

function draw(data) {

  // This is the total size of the data
  var dataLength = data.length;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, window.innerWidth]);

  // create a rect
  var rects = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "first");

  rects.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
      "fill": function(d) {
        return colorScale(d);
      },
      "x": function(d, i) {
        return x(d);
      },
      "y": yPos,
      "width": window.innerWidth / dataLength - padding,
      "height": 50
    });

    yPos += 60;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In the snippet, `draw` has two parameters: the data array and the vertical position of the rectangles.

EDIT: There are several ways to dynamically place one row below the previous. The most elegant ways are, of course, those that get the position of the previous row. The most simple way, not that elegant, is simply using a counter:

```js
var data1 = d3.range(0, 50);
var data2 = d3.range(51, 100); //new data
var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();
var yPos = 10;

var padding = 2;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": window.innerWidth,
    "height": window.innerHeight
  });

draw(data1);
draw(data2);
draw(data2);
draw(data1);
draw(data1);

function draw(data) {

  // This is the total size of the data
  var dataLength = data.length;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, window.innerWidth]);

  // create a rect
  var rects = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "first");

  rects.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
      "fill": function(d) {
        return colorScale(d);
      },
      "x": function(d, i) {
        return x(d);
      },
      "y": yPos,
      "width": window.innerWidth / dataLength - padding,
      "height": 50
    });

    yPos += 60;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah that is the question, you answered it. But if there were more than two say 50, then would it be better to place it in a loop? One more thing, the draw function takes in two parameters. Is there a way to not pass in the vertical position and let the program dynamically place it under the first set of colors?